# Problem with wireless card RTL8723ae on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

I can't connect to any wireless networks on my PC, none show up in the gnome network manager. Before this I've tried the WICD network manager to no avail and  I have the following info:

```
sudo lsshow -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f7803fff
```

Which I figured means I have no working driver and so I got one recommended in another thread by the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
make 
sudo make install
```

Which grants a successfull output and so I try to unload the current driver and set the new one:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723ae
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723ae
```

Which trows the following error:

```
install /bin/false 
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:959 command_do() Error running install command for rtlwifi
 modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723ae': Operation not permitted
```

And thats as far as I've gotten and I'm pretty much stumped. Any pointers?

**Attempted fixes:**
26∕01∕16 Manually moved file `rtl8723ae.ko` to `\lib\modules\3.13.0-76-generic\kernel\net\wireless`. No change

25/01/16 Uninstalled by `sudo make uninstall` and installed from PPA by `sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms`. No change

25/01/16 Added PPA from `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi`
 and grabbed the firmware, and copied it to `/lib/firmware`